# Change variable from input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been learning some jQuery and using w3schools. My intention is to allow the user to bind any key on their keyboard to the currently hardcoded key. I tried creating a variable and having that changed based on the input of the text field to change the keycode but haven't had any luck (Just like how you see in some games when they allow you to map a key to another). I was researching on w3schools and I believe I could use switch case, but I believe that would be too long and not tidy?

Here is what I have so far. (Alert doesn't seem to work here, going to the actual JSFiddle via the hyperlink works though)

```js
$('input').bind("binding", function(e) {
  alert("Backspace"); //Pop up to see
});

$('input').keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 8) { // 8 = backspace
    $(this).trigger("binding"); //will allow the message to be displayed
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Try it here <input type="text"> Change the input <input class type="text">
```

Any suggestions are grateful. Thank you

Comment: I don't see any variable there...?

Comment: Oh I meant that I tried using that. I didn't know whether that was possible using that so removed. But that is the way to do it then? @T.J.Crowder

Comment: As an aside, please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong; as in this case. `bind()` has been deprecated and should not be used. Use `on()` instead. If you want to learn, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/) are far more comprehensive and accurate.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for that information. I will use https://api.jquery.com/ from now on as it's really helpful and packed with info. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this for binding one key to backspace. It takes input from the first input element and the key pressed is then bounded to the backspace and only that key will function as a backspace key

```js
$('#try').bind("binding", function(e) {
  alert("Backspace"); //Pop up to see
});
var a;
$('#change').keyup(function(e) {
  a = e.keyCode;
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
$('#try').keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == a) {
    $(this).trigger("binding"); //will allow the message to be displayed
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Press the key you want to bind to backspace <input type="text" id="change"><br> Change the input <input id="try" type="text">
```

Comment: Ah, that is a nice way of going about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By default the binded key will be Backspace. You can change the key by typing something in the first input. It will take only one character.
Then when that key is input in the second input field the message will be triggered.

**Explanation:**
The keycode of the key entered in the first input is saved in the `key_code` variable and used later on in the other key_up event to check whether it matches

```js
    var key_code = 8
    $('#changekey').keyup("input", function(e) {
      key_code = e.keyCode;
    });

    $('input').on("binding", function(e) {
      alert("Backspace"); //Pop up to see
    });
    $('#text').keyup(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == key_code) //8 = backspace
      {
        $(this).trigger("binding"); //will allow the message to be displayed
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Try it here <input type="text" id="changekey" maxlength = 1 > Change the input <input class type="text" id="text">
```